# Validate file name(or folder name) in iPhone

Tags: iphone, regex, nspredicate

I am trying to validate a file name/ folder name when user try to change the name.
I know I should use Regex/ NSPredicate. However, I didn't figure out after hours researching.
Appreciate if any experts can help me out.
Thanks a lot.

Was suggested by Madhumal Gunetileke: 
I revised his code as below. It works for my case.

```
NSCharacterSet * set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\/:*?\"<>|"];
    if ([newName rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"illegal Name");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Validate based on what? What do you consider valid and what invalid?

Comment: @Cullen SUN, Can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks Dani. I am checking whether user inputs contain any of the characters in "\ / : * ? " < > |". Those characters are what I found from somewhere: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177506. Not sure iOS has the exactly the same rule or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply looking out to check whether the new name users provide are valid or not, you could try something like this;

```
NSString *yourString = @"<the name you want to verify comes here>";
NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"] invertedSet];
if ([yourString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"NOT Legal");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Legal");
}
```